# Assign current record to recordID

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

So I am trying to assign the current record I am on to recordID but I am having some issues.

Apex controller

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String returnid()
{

     String idofpage; 
     idofpage = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id'); 
     return idofpage;
}
```

My JS controller

```
        handleUploadFinished: function (component, event, helper) {
     var getid = component.get('c.returnid');   

      getid.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            alert("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());
        }
        else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            alert("INCOMPLETE");
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
         alert("Error");
        }
    });     

       $A.enqueueAction(getid);   

    // Get the list of uploaded files
    //var uploadedFiles = event.getParam("files");
    //alert("Files uploaded : " + uploadedFiles.length);
},
```

Component

```
 <aura:attribute name="myRecordId" type="String" description="Record to which the files should be attached" />
<lightning:fileUpload label="Attach receipt"
    multiple="true"
    accept=".pdf, .png"
    recordId="{!v.myRecordId}"
    onuploadfinished="{!c.handleUploadFinished}" />
```

My JS controller shows 'error' as the alert. When I hard code a value in my Apex controller it does not complain leading me to believe I am getting the id of the page wrong.

What I plan to do is assign the current page id to recordId in my component. Is there a better approach then what I am currently doing? If not, how can I get the current id of the page in my Apex controller to pass to my JS controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing two different contexts. `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')` is useful for Visualforce, but you're writing a lightning component. If you lightning component has a recordId (because it implements force:hasRecordId) then it has a hidden attribute named recordId. So all you have to do to get it from your controller is `component.get("v.recordId")` and no Apex is required. So in your example:

```
handleUploadFinished: function (component, event, helper) {
    var getid = component.get('v.recordId');     

    // Get the list of uploaded files
    //var uploadedFiles = event.getParam("files");
    //alert("Files uploaded : " + uploadedFiles.length);
},
```